# No grub menu after firmware update

Tags: 16.04, uefi, dell, secure-boot, firmware

I just allowed my system to restart and install a firmware update on a Dell XPS 15 (9560) which went smooth and was successful.

Upon reboot however it shows the following message then boots to (Windows) automatic repair (non-existent; left it in case I want to reinstall windows with the restore image I made). This occurs when the first entry (in the second image) is selected (the default now).

[image]

In the boot options this is what I see. No Ubuntu entry as it used to be.

[image]

I launched a live USB (seen above) and I can see all (encrypted) partitions still there.

In the bios setup when I click add boot option I can find two relevant directories (Ubuntu and Boot). Under Boot there's only one entry (bootx64.efi).under Ubuntu there are a number of entries (fwupx64.efi, grubx64.efi, grub.cfg,  shimx64.efi, mmx64.efi, fbx64.efi)

I've never dealt with similar stuff so your help is appreciated.

My best guess is that grub has been overwritten or corrupted? Or it it related to the secure boot opinion I have?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a boot option n the BIOS setup. I thought it was logical to first try `\EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi` which worked. I am back in my system. Here is a clearer explanation:

- Reboot into the BIOS setup
- Click `Add Boot Option`
- Give it a name (e.g. Ubuntu)
- For `File Name`, under `\EFI\Ubuntu` directory select `grubx64.efi`.
- Save the settings and exit.
- You should see the grub soon.

As a precaution, once in my system I ran `sudo update-grub` and `sudo grub-install` though both are redundant to each other.